# How can you sort by descending date/time on the Kibana “Discover” tab

Tags: kibana

Kibana is a tool that exposes data stored in Elastic Search. Is there way to sort the data on the discover tab by descending date/time, kind of like an EventLog. I have various messages with different index/types being emitted from my programs.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After expanding an row-item, you can sort by clicking the icon that makes a field a column heading.  Then it may appear with an up/down arrow next to it allowing you to sort ascending/descending.

However, if you have an index-pattern that crosses multiple indexes, seems like you are able to select the column, but no sort icon will appear.

Reference: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-sort-by-date-time-on-kibana-discover/126804